# Convert vs. CType

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, ctype

I am somewhat confused about presence of two *seemingly* identical VB.NET functions: `CType(args)` and `Convert.ToType(args)`. I'm fairly new to .NET and VB in general, so I'm not quite sure whether one of them is a VB6 legacy or they actually have different purposes / uses / limitations. Is one of the them newer / safer? Are there reasons to use one but not the other?

Cheers! = )

Comment: Please stop putting the programming language in the question title... that's what tags are for

Comment: Won't do it again. I've seen others do that, thought it might be a good idea. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CType is from VB6 times and is not the best when it comes to efficiency. You should be able to use `Convert.ToXxxx()` methods for convertion and `TryCast()` and `DirectCast()` for casting instead of `CType()`.

Comment: Not true. `CType` was never in the VB6. I think you are confusing this with `CInt`, `CDbl`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

See [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289509). (Conversion Functions, CType, DirectCast, and System.Convert Section).

The conclusion of that section is as follows:

> **Recommendation**: For most conversions, use the intrinsic language
>   conversion keywords (including **CType**) for brevity and clarity and to
>   allow compiler optimizations when converting between types. Use
>   **DirectCast** for converting Object to String and for extracting value
>   types boxed in Object variables when the embedded type is known (that
>   is, coercion is not necessary).